# Advice on design

Tags: database-design

I am new to databases and overall data designs. I am developing an English learning website that keeps progress of your studies.

**My problem:**
Every lesson has a checkbox which marks your progress.

Should I make a column for every checkbox and lesson?,
Or make a Json file and save it to the database?

Could you please give a few tips on this? I want it to be efficient, and save it every time when value changes.

Comment: So there are a few additional questions I'd need before proceeding: 1. are the number of checkboxes the same for each lesson? Will this always be the case? 2. Are the lessons part of a larger lesson plan? 3. Do the lessons need to be completed in order?

Comment: 1.Each lesson has a checkbox, every time.
2. Could be, Some yes, some not.
3.No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a database to track this information, you should use multiple tables to store the information and add rows to them as needed.

A simple example:

1. a USER table which has a unique User ID as the Public Key and then columns for standard user information like username, email, etc.
2. a LESSON table which has a Lesson ID as the Public Key and columns for Lesson Name and contents
3. a PROGRESS table which correlates users with their progression through the lessons. Any time a User completes a lesson, add a row with the User ID ad Lesson ID public keys.

This would get more complicated if you include tests as part of the lessons instead of just a simple progress indicator.

You generally want to avoid modifying the database schema by doing things like adding columns. Adding, deleting, and modifying rows, yes. Making associations between tables (like how the PROGRESS doesn't store all the user or lesson information in every row, it uses the public key to make the connection), also yes.

Edit: a note regarding "Keys". Every table requires a column (could also be a set of columns, but pretend I didn't say that) where every row has a unique value. It can be something that has meaning, like a User ID, or it could be an incrementing integer, or a UUID (a string that is complex enough that duplication is statistically ridiculously improbable). This unique column is the Key that the database uses to filter and correlate information between tables. I can't think of a Key that would have meaning for the PROGRESS table, so I'd just use an incrementing integer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really helpful, Tests would be a separate function, but I reckon it would use the same schema.